# Javascript nested Events

Tags: javascript, events, nested

I want to make a neseted event. By nested event i mean something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onFocus='validStartDate()' name="start_date" id="startDate" />
```

Javascript:

```
function checkCorrectStart()
{
    document.getElementById("startDate").className = "focus";
    document.getElementById("startDate").onChange = function(){
        validStartDate();   
    };
}

function validStartDate()
{
   re = /^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/;
   var aux = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
   var valid = false;

   if (aux.match(re))
   {
       document.getElementById("startDate").className = "correct";
       valid = true;
   }
   else
   {
       document.getElementById("startDate").className = "wrong";
   }
   return valid;
}
```

The idea is that when a user focus on the input box it will make a yellow shadow around the input.Then when the user changes the content of that input box, it will verify if it's correct and make a green shadow if correct or a red shadow if it isn't correct.

Any idea or any other suggestion on how to do this, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: And I think you meant to put the checkCorrectStart() in the onFocus attribute. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `jQuery` (using plain javascript) then you can try this

```
window.onload=function(){
    var el=document.getElementById("startDate");
    el.onfocus=function(){
        var currentClass=el.parentNode.className;
        if(currentClass!='correct') el.parentNode.className = "wrong";
    }
    el.onchange = validStartDate;   
    el.onkeyup = validStartDate;   
}

function validStartDate()
{
   var el=document.getElementById("startDate");
   var re = /^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/;
   var aux = el.value;
   var valid = false;

   if (aux.match(re))
   {
       el.parentNode.className = "correct";
       valid = true;
   }
   else
   {
       el.parentNode.className = "wrong";
       valid = false;
   }
   return valid;
}
```

I didn't include the `css` here, it's available in the demo but you need to use in your page.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/896qz/5/).